# Gremlin : Multiple filter condition "OR"

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I want to query my TITAN 0.4 graph, based on two filter conditions with "OR" logical operator (return vertices if either of conditions is true).

I searched this on http://sql2gremlin.com/, but only "AND" operator is given,

My requirement is something as given below:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Products
 WHERE Discontinued = 1
   OR UnitsInStock = 0

g.V('type','product').has('discontinued', true) "OR"
                     .has('unitsInStock', 0)
```

Please help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do:

```
g.V('type','product').or(_().has('discontinued', true), _().has('unitsInStock', 0))
```

See the [or step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#or-step) in GremlinDocs.